# Big Image in the center sourrounded by smaler Images with Felxbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'll try to center a larger image in the center (450px x 200px) sourrounded by smaler ones (each: 150px x 100px).

So this is what I want:
[image]

And this is what I get:

````css
.boxarea {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      flex-flow: wrap;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      align-content: flex-start;
}

.box {
    margin: auto;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background: #333;
}

.big {
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
}
```
```
````

```html
<div class="boxarea">
<div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
<div class="box big" style="background-color: #999;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
</div>
```

It seems that the vertical images centers around the larger one, how can I change this?

Comment: I mean Divs not images

Comment: flexbox is only good if you need to control one direction. Height or width. In this case, you need to control both. CSS-Grid is the way to go in this case as it is able to control both, height an width at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS grid

```css
.boxarea {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
}

.big {
  grid-row: 2/ span 2;
  grid-column: 2/ span 3;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxarea">
  <div class="box big" style="background-color: #999;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #333;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #666;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool perfect! Do you know how I can use the grid when I shrink it? So how to display the big box on top and then the rest of the boxes three at every line,,,?

Comment: It works perfect Temani, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

With CSS grid you can achieve this easily

```css
.boxarea {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.box {
  height: 75px;
  border: red 1px solid
}

.big {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 4 / 5;
  background: green;
  height: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="boxarea">
  <div class="box big"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't leave comments about votes, either your own or speculations about others'. Thank you.